# To remove a digit in middle position using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server name `Barcode`; there are 14 digit numbers or 13 digits number. Now I want to remove the 7 in the 14 digit number. Is there any possibility to remove the 7 from middle position?

IF it is 14 digit no:

```
11010077007563  -14 digit no (7 should be removed for 14 digit no in the 7th position)
```

Expected result:

```
1101007007563
```

Answer (score 1):

check this, this will remove 7th digit if length is 14 else given whatever the value.

```
declare @barcode_no bigint = 11010077007563

select case when len(@barcode_no) = 14 then stuff(@barcode_no,7,1,'') else @barcode_no end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SQL Stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) or [SQL Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to replace nth character in a string.

@Ajay2707 already shown you using SQL STUFF method to obtain the result.

```
declare @barcode_no bigint = 11010077007563
```

> Replace

```
select case when len(@barcode_no) = 14 then replace(@barcode_no,8,'') else 
@barcode_no end
```

> Stuff

```
select case when len(@barcode_no) = 14 then stuff(@barcode_no,7,1,'') else 
@barcode_no end
```